# Saving each feature in PNG format along with map canvas in certain scale using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, qgsmapcanvas

I want to export each feature by zooming to certain scale (eg 1:25000 where feature will be inside map canvas) and save into PNG format. I know function

```
iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage("image_path")
```

but how to iterate each feature with fix scale value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following script. Specify `folder`

```
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
layer = iface.activeLayer()
ids = layer.allFeatureIds()

scale = 25000
delay = 250 # 250 milisecond
folder = "/path/to/folder/"

def prepare():
    if ids:
        fid = ids.pop()
        canvas.zoomToFeatureIds(layer, [fid])
        canvas.zoomScale(scale)
        canvas.refresh()
        QTimer.singleShot(delay, lambda: save_as_image(fid))

def save_as_image(fid):
    file_name = folder + str(fid) + ".png"    
    canvas.saveAsImage(file_name)
    QTimer.singleShot(delay, prepare)

prepare()
```

Comment: this code works perfectly inside python console of qgis. While i try to implement inside plugin the save_as_image function is not being called from lambda:save_as_image function.Can  you please suggest